# Multiple line tool tip in wpf using c#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I want to use multiple line tool tip in wpf
but thie is look like

```
line 1 
    line2
```

but i want to display this miltiple line tool tip in the given format

```
line 1
line 2
```

Answer (score 11):

I personally prefer to embed `&#x0a;`(new line) into the strings I'll be using as tooltips.

ex. `Tooltip="line 1 &#x0a;line 2"`

I can then load the strings from resource files and conveniently apply them if I wish without having to go through any additional formatting.

Comment: It's also possible to use the slightly shorter: `&#10;`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to do it with a Label as an example:

```
<Label>
    <Label.ToolTip>
        <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock>Line 1</TextBlock>
             <TextBlock>Line 2</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Label.ToolTip>
</Label>
```

Comment: I want to use to set tool tip text from resource file

Comment: You should mention that as part of your question then.  What does your string look like in the resource file?   Does it have line breaks?  Are you using data binding in WPF?  Are you just setting in the code behind?

Answer (score 3):

That worked for me and I don't see anything similar in the answers:

```
<[ParentControl].ToolTip>
    <TextBlock>
        Some text here.
        <LineBreak/>    
        And more text in a new line.
    </TextBlock>
</[ParentControl].ToolTip>
```